# Go Revel SSL cert Intermediate/chain certificate and forward to 443

Tags: ssl, go, https, x509certificate, revel

I'm using Revel for a small app and added SSL. When I update the config to point to http.port = 443, requests to port 80 are rejected instead of being forwarded. Is there a way to fix this on the Revel Framework? 
Also, I get the error "The certificate is not trusted in all web browsers. You may need to install an Intermediate/chain certificate to link it to a trusted root certificate." Is there a way to install the Intermediate/chain certificate on Revel? Thank you.

```
# The port on which to listen.
http.port = 443

# Whether to use SSL or not.
http.ssl = true

# Path to an X509 certificate file, if using SSL.
http.sslcert = /root/go/src/saml/AlphaCerts/cert.crt

# Path to an X509 certificate key, if using SSL.
http.sslkey = /root/go/src/saml/star_home_com.key
```

Comment: @JiangYD: what are you talking about?

Comment: @vinniyo, you need to chain the intermediate cert just like you would in most other systems -- concatenate CA's intermediate cert to your own.

Comment: Thank you JimB. I've appended the intermediate cert and it's working now.

Comment: Port 80 redirection answered in another question - http://stackoverflow.com/a/33563755/757102

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Revel doesn't forward to port 443 when SSL enabled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33553583/revel-doesnt-forward-to-port-443-when-ssl-enabled)